# Null check operator used on a null value inherited widget flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i am having this null check error, i am creating a inherited widget of global keys , can anyone pls help me to solve this

```
class KeysToBeInherited extends InheritedWidget {
  const KeysToBeInherited(
      {Key? key,
      required this.add,
      required this.card,
      required this.color,
      required this.bepy,
      required this.me,
      required this.publish,
      required this.child})
      : super(key: key, child: child);

  final GlobalKey add;
  final GlobalKey card;
  final GlobalKey color;
  final GlobalKey me;
  final GlobalKey bepy;
  final GlobalKey publish;
  final Widget child;

  static KeysToBeInherited of(BuildContext context) {
    final KeysToBeInherited? result =
        context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<KeysToBeInherited>();

    return result!;
  }

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(covariant KeysToBeInherited oldWidget) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

..........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Give the entire code please

Comment: this is the whole code i am building this class for of context ex KeysToBeInherited.of(context).add

Comment: we don't see the code calling this method

Answer (score 0):

Check if result is not null and then use result!

Comment: how to check the result

Comment: if(result != null) {return result!; }

Comment: context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<KeysToBeInherited>();   I think this value is null

Comment: i have also done this method if(result != null) {return result!; }but same error